# Scrapy: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm writing a spider on Scrapy splash and I'm starting to get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\splash\project\project\spiders\scrapy.py", line 5
start_urls = [
             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Here are the code lines where I get it:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class ScrapySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spide1"
    start_urls = [
                'link1',
                'link2', 
                etc
```

Why am I getting this mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: where did you put the ], and try to move the links left to the 9th char (2nd level of indentation) and or move the [ and ] on the first and last lines until it works. In Python indentations have to be exactly met!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was two spaces before def

After adding 2 spaces - problem has been solved

Comment: This explanation does not make any sense. It does not say `def` anywhere in your example code. The problem - revealed by carefully checking the [raw source of your original attempt at the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7eafdb62-57ec-40a3-be3f-fe02cb57db59/view-source) - is that you used a tab before `name = "spide1"`, but spaces before `start_urls = [`.